# How can I use pandas/dask to normalize columns across 12k csv files (50gb) in a google bucket in a memory-friendly way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have about 12,000 csv files (50gb) stored in a google bucket that have almost similar column structures.
However, there are some differences.
Notably:

- Not all files have all columns.
- Some files' header row does not start on the first row. Instead, there may be a merged block of cells that take up the first few rows and columns that provide a summary of report parameters used to generate the report.

**Overview of the goal:**

1. Gather an extensive list of column headers from all files
2. Use that extensive list of column headers to normalize all files, so they have matching schemas

   - removing any rows that precede the header row
   - adding any missing columns to each file
   - adding the filename and google storage folder path as static columns to each file

**Psuedo-Code Thought Process**

**Pre-cursor:** I'm a bit lost as to how to approach this as I'm not very savvy with `pandas`/`numpy`. But, I do have a general idea of the steps I'd need to take in order to accomplish this.

1. Utilize `pandas.read_csv(..., nrows=25)` to peek at each file's contents
2. Maybe look at the total columns of the sheet's x-range vs each row's column count to determine when we reach the header columns row?
3. Always assign `str` to every single column `dtype` (to keep memory usage down)
4. ?

**Note:**
The machine used is limited to about 16gb RAM and downloading the entire folder locally is also not viable due to storage limitations.

Once the files are normalized I can handle creating a BigQuery LoadJob to ingest the file data.

Answer (score 1):

If all columns started on the first row, I would have used something like this (not tested):

```py
from dask import delayed, compute
@delayed
def get_cols(file):
    cols = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1).columns 
    return {'file': file, 'cols': cols}

from glob import glob
files = glob('*csv') # or an appropriate list of files
cols = compute([get_cols(f) for f in files])
```

Next, I would convert cols into a dataframe and create a scheme that is satisfactory. This depends on your data and goals, so can't help much here.

Since there is the issue of files that do not start on the first row I would either use `try/except` within the `get_cols` or implement another logic to obtain the column names, which also depends on the data, so can't help more here.